# Using JRuby in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, jruby

I'm trying to use JRuby in projects created in Android studio.  I have built the latest (as of 9/10/2014) JRuby, and have completely updated Android Studio.  I have a working app that I can use to test.  I have a copy of jruby.jar in the MyApp/app/libs directory.  Once there I right-clicked on jruby.jar and selected "Add as Library", which presumably did something (though what I am not certain), and have added the line "compile files('libs/jruby.jar')" to the build.gradle that is in MyApp/app/.

In one of the class files I have "import org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer;", which Android Studio says is fine (if I hadn't added jruby.jar as a library I couldn't include this without an error).  Then in one of the working methods I say "ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();".  When I run this method the app will crash.  I won't try to include the whole error message, but the important part seems to be:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.jruby.embed.internal.AbstractLocalContextProvider.<init>(AbstractLocalContextProvider.java:42)
        at org.jruby.embed.internal.SingletonLocalContextProvider.<init>(SingletonLocalContextProvider.java:88)
        at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.getProviderInstance(ScriptingContainer.java:248)
        at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.<init>(ScriptingContainer.java:228)
        at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.<init>(ScriptingContainer.java:185)
```

and

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported Java version: 0.9
        at org.jruby.RubyInstanceConfig.initGlobalJavaVersion(RubyInstanceConfig.java:1858)
        at org.jruby.RubyInstanceConfig.<clinit>(RubyInstanceConfig.java:1608)
```

At least, those are the parts that make sense to me.  I hav no idea why I would get the error "java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported Java version: 0.9", since I am using 1.8.0_20.  The rest of the errors I cannot follow.  When I click on any of the files giving me an error (say AbstractLocalContextProvider.java:42) Android Studio will show the file but also say "Sources not found".  That could be the problem, but I don't know why it can't find the sources.

Thanks for any help,

Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uwe Kubosch (‏@donv70) was able to tell me the solution to this via Twitter, so credit to him, but I wanted to post the solution here in case anyone else needs it.

It was Java version that was causing the problem.  In Ruboto the problem is solved here: https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/blob/master/assets/src/org/ruboto/JRubyAdapter.java#L137
and for use in Android Studio it is necessary only to include the line: `System.setProperty("jruby.bytecode.version", "1.6");`
The number of course can be 1.6, 1.7, or 1.8, depending on your version of Java.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an interoperability problem between JRuby and the Dalvik VM (don't forget that you're running against Dalvik, not the Java VM).

There's a bug report at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5774 that may lead you in the right direction.
It's kind of old, and is marked 'fixed', but maybe it'll provide some clues?

Comment: Yeah, I see that. They pretty much say that it should be ignored and not cause a fail. According to http://jruby.org/2012/10/22/jruby-1-7-0.html they fixed this issue (for Ruboto at least) in version 1.7.0 of JRuby.  I'm using 1.7.15 and it seems to be back.